# Viral genome assembly using broad viral ngs pipeline?

Tags: genome, assembly, covid-19, sars-cov-2

I am trying to assemble RNA virus genome using Broad Viral NGS pipeline [BROAD VIRAL NGS PIPELINE](https://viral-ngs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/assembly.html). I am two questions :

1) As this pipeline requires unaligned bam format as input, how do I convert fastq to bam ?

2) Some of the tools like   assemble_trinity require Trimmomatic clipDb. How can I get this clipDb ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already using the Broad Tools sets you can use [Picard FastqToSam](https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#FastqToSam) to make the conversion

As far a clipDb I am unfamiliar with that and a quick google search and look at the trimmomatic manual were unhelpful